# Installing express 4.x with its middlewares?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

How can i install Express and bring its middlewares, that were in the legacy version?

Sort of `npm install -g`, but which brings the middleware back, and why Express team dont do that?

Comment: `npm install` those you intend to use as well -- http://expressjs.com/resources/middleware.html. They still exist, just as their own packages now.

Comment: yes, but i wished that express will consider them as dependecies and bring them by only making `npm install` for once.

Comment: @Abdelouahab - you can wish all you want.  It is what it is and only someone on the team can tell you exactly why they changed it.  Go install the external modules you need, add one line of code to `require()` them in and you're done.  It literally takes less time than it did for me to respond to you here.

Comment: that is what i did, but it was not as easy as it was just installing one command ....

Answer (score 1):

Express 4 has unbundled itself from many of the middleware that was previously built-in.  Those pieces of middleware are now available as separate modules which you can `npm install` into your project and then `require()` into your app as needed.

We could guess as to why they unbundled things (make Express more focused, more streamlined, more open to alternate middleware and more modular - generally considered desirable attributes), but only someone from the Express team could answer exactly as to why they changed it.

For example, I'm including the `body-parser` and `cookie-parser` modules into my Express 4 project so I can use their functionality as middleware.  Each module you might be interested in, explains how to load it and insert it into the middleware stack.

Comment: it will not be easy for a new comer (like me) googling and coming to stackoverflow, made me choose express, since it is the 'tornado equivalent on python', but i found that the version 4, there is no 'battery included' .. so i hope they will add them as dependecies, they can develop them apart, but they can at least call them from the installation

Comment: @Abdelouahab - You make a case for a separately downloadable option that is Express plus a bunch of the more popular modules.  That would not be too hard to do if the various folks responsible for the different modules could agree to coordinate on maintaining it.  But, we here on StackOverflow aren't the ones to convince.  We report on how it is now. If you want to change it, you will have to find a way to communicate with people who actually work on those projects and could actually implement what you want or make one yourself. Personally, I like the modularity is has now.

Comment: i hope they will land on that post one day, and think to include the middlewares they develop appart as dependecies...